# How do I grep recursively through .gz files?

Tags: files, grep, search, recursive, compression

I am using a script to regularly download my gmail messages that compresses the raw .eml into .gz files. The script creates a folder for each day, and then compresses every message into its own file.

I would like a way to search through this archive for a "string."

Grep alone doesn't appear to do it. I also tried SearchMonkey.

Comment: None of the answer have worked so far for me! Did anything work for you?

Comment: @achhainsan if they don't work for you, please ask a new question, explain exactly what you are trying to do, and exactly how they fail. You can link back to this question for reference. These are very standard approaches, so if they don't work, you are probably requiring something slightly different to what is being requested here.

Answer (score 213):

If you want to grep recursively in all .eml.gz files in the current directory, you can use:

```
find . -name \*.eml.gz -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep "STRING"
```

You have to escape the first `*` so that the shell does not interpret it. `-print0` tells find to print a null character after each file it finds; `xargs -0` reads from standard input and runs the command after it for each file; `zgrep` works like `grep`, but uncompresses the file first.

Comment: '-print0' and '-0' are not mandatory. xargs uses '\n' by default.

Comment: They're necessary if there might be space characters in the paths; there's no reason other than complexity not to use them.

Comment: `zgrep` actually seems faster than `grep` run on uncompressed files. It must be because compressed files can be read off the HD and decompressed faster than reading an uncompressed file from the HD.

Comment: @JaimeM. `xargs` uses _blanks_ (whitespace) by default. Sure, files almost never have newlines in them, but spaces are not unheard of (even if most UNIXy types frown on them). That said, you can simplify without worrying about whitespace even more easily: `find . -name '*.eml.gz' -exec zgrep "STRING" {} +` That gets the same many arguments per-launch of `xargs`, the safety of `-print0`/`-0`, and all without the overhead of an extra process launch and piping, and fairly concisely. `-exec` with `+` is POSIX specified, so it should be on most semi-recent UNIX-like systems to my knowledge.

Comment: @Jared Is there a way to do a wildcard search only knowing the beginning of the file pattern? For example, I have .gz files that have date/time stamps at the end of them. `ABCLog04_18_18_2_21.gz`

Is there a way to recursively look for files beginning with ABC*. I tried replacing `\*.eml.gz` in your example above with `ABCLog*` and get an error about file format.: `find: paths must precede expression: ABCLog-2018-03-12-10-16-1.log.gz
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
`

Comment: This just dumps all content from all the flies...

Answer (score 90):

There's a lot of confusion here because there isn't just one `zgrep`. I have two versions on my system, `zgrep` from `gzip` and `zgrep` from [`zutils`](http://www.nongnu.org/zutils/zutils.html). The former is just a wrapper script that calls `gzip -cdfq`. It doesn't support the `-r, --recursive` switch.<sup>1</sup>
The latter is a `c++` program and it [supports](http://www.nongnu.org/zutils/manual/zutils_manual.html#Zgrep) the `-r, --recursive` option.
Running `zgrep --version | head -n 1` will reveal which one (if any) of them is the default:

```
zgrep (gzip) 1.6
```

is the wrapper script,

```
zgrep (zutils) 1.3
```

is the `cpp` executable.
If you have the latter you could run:

```
zgrep 'pattern' -r --format=gz /path/to/dir
```

Anyway, as suggested, `find` + `zgrep` will work equally well with either version of `zgrep`:

```
find /path/to/dir -name '*.gz' -exec zgrep -- 'pattern' {} +
```

---

If `zgrep` is missing from your system (highly unlikely) you could try with:

```
find /path/to/dir -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c 'gzip -cd "$0" | grep -- "pattern"' {} \;
```

but there's a major downside: you won't know where the matches are as there's no file name prepended to the matching lines .

---

<sup>1: [because it would be problematic](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gzip/2006-12/msg00075.html)</sup>

Comment: if `zgrep` from zutils is not available you can install it in Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install zutils`.

Comment: Continued from @therealmarv ... and then Ubuntu will use the zutils zgrep instead of the gzip one. Then -r works!

Comment: Is there a way to print the line number of the file the pattern is matched on?

Comment: @DogEatDog - just like `grep -n`, `zgrep -n` will print line no.s. It's in the manual...

Answer (score 11):

`ag` is a variant of  `grep`, with some nice extra features.

- has -z option for compressed files,
- has many of ack features.
- it is fast

So:

```
ag -r -z your-pattern-goes-here   folder
```

If not installed,

```
apt-get install silversearcher-ag   (debian and friends)
yum install the_silver_searcher     (fedora)
brew install the_silver_searcher    (mac)
```

---

(edit in Sep 2021 \thanks(x-yuri))

Also consider `rg` (recursive grep) that has `-z` option

```
rg -z your-pattern-goes-here   folder
```

rg has also a large set of useful options. If necessary:

```
apt install ripgrep
```

Comment: I get `ag: truncated file: Success` as a result. Any other flag should I add?

Comment: Great tool but still has some issues [1280](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/1280) [1348](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/1348). Now it needs flags `ag --search-binary -z "quick"`

Comment: [`rg`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) also supports the `-z` switch.

Comment: @x-yuri, thank you -- rg seems a very powerful tool!

Answer (score 5):

Recursion alone is easy:

```
   -r, --recursive
          Read all files  under  each  directory,  recursively,  following
          symbolic  links  only  if they are on the command line.  This is
          equivalent to the -d recurse option.

   -R, --dereference-recursive
          Read all files under each directory,  recursively.   Follow  all
          symbolic links, unlike -r.
```

However, for compressed files you need something like:

```
shopt globstar 
for file in /path/to/directory/**/*gz; do zcat ""$file" | grep pattern; done
```

`path/to/directory` should be the parent directory that contains the subdirectories for each day.

---

`zgrep` is the obvious answer but, unfortunately, it does not support the `-r` flag. From `man zgrep`:

> These grep options will   cause   zgrep    to    terminate    with    an    error    code: (-[d**rR**zZ]|--di*|--exc*|--inc*|--rec*|--nu*).

Answer (score 5):

If your system has zgrep, you can simply

`zgrep -irs your-pattern-goes-here the-folder-to-search-goes-here/`

If your system does not have zgrep, you can use the **find** command to run zcat and grep against each file like so:

`find the-folder-to-search-goes-here/ -name '*.gz' \
 -exec sh -c 'echo "Searching {}" ; zcat "{}" | grep your-pattern-goes-here ' \;`

Comment: Forgive me greeness on this...

the files to be searched through are a couple of layers deep. ~/gmvault-db/db/2015-02 contains a folder for each month archived, and then underneath that the .gz files for that month are stored. If I'm search for .mil within that whole tree, is that what I would do?

find ~/gmvault-db/db/ -name '*.gz' \
 -exec sh -c 'echo "Searching {}" ; zcat "{}" | grep .mil ' \;

Comment: That's fine - the "r" in -irs will cause zgrep to search recursively. The find command operates recursively by default, so any file which ends in .gz will be zcatted and passed into grep. (and the {} will be expanded to the relative path of the file which is about to be searched). So when you get a hit, it will be preceded by 

`Searching ~/gmvault-db/db/2015-02/03/whatever.gz`

Comment: Here's what I get back: find: "paths must precede expression:  -exec"

Here's the command I used: 
 find ~/gmvault-db/db/ -name '*.gz' \ -exec sh -c 'echo "Searching {}" ; zcat "{}" | grep .mil ' \;

Comment: take out the backslash between the '*.gz' and the -exec.

Comment: `zgrep` won't take the `-r` flag for some reason. That's mention in `man zgrep` (also see my answer).

Comment: @terdon - depends on the `zgrep` flavor: `zgrep` from `gzip` won't take the `-r` flag but `zgrep` from `zutils` will, see my answer (it's actually a comment but too long to fit in a comment block).

Comment: @don_crissti I see, thanks, I didn't know of zutil's `zgrep`.

Answer (score 1):

> xzgrep -l "string" ./*/*.eml.gz

xzgrep is a derivative of the zgrep utils (less /bin/xzgrep)

From the Man page:

> xzgrep  invokes  grep(1)  on  files which may be either uncompressed or compressed with xz(1), lzma(1), gzip(1),  bzip2(1),  or  lzop(1).   All
>    options specified are passed directly to grep(1).

-l print the matching file name

-R for recursion will not work as it's specifically prohibited in the script, however simple shell globbing should get us there

> ./*/*.eml.gz

from a relative path where ./today/sample.eml.gz, match on all instances of that are one level below our relative position in the shell, that ends with ".eml.gz"